# whats wrong with this send.php?

Tags: php

```
        <?php
        date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

          $to = "ry@cbpar.com"; 
          $subject = "New Membership Sign Up"; 
          $message = "First Name:" $_POST['one'];
                     "Last Name:" $_POST['two'];
                     "Email:" $_POST['three'];
                     "Password:" $_POST['four'];
                     "Phone:" $_POST['five'];
                     "Address 1:" $_POST['six'];
                     "Address 2:" $_POST['seven'];
                     "Pick Up City:" $_POST['eight'];
                     "State:" $_POST['nine'];


          mail($to, $subject, $message);
        ?>
```

can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code? the form seems to not send , labeled everything the way it supposed to but not sure why its not working

this is the form,

```
    <table width="551" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
          <form method="post" action="send.php">
              <tr>
                <td width="108" class="TextAB"><div align="right"><strong>First Name:</strong></div></td>
                <td width="431"><label>
                  <div align="left">
                    <input name="one" type="text" id="001" size="50"/>
                    </div>
                </label></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="right"><span class="TextAB"><strong>Last Name:</strong></span></div></td>
                <td><div align="left">
                  <input name="two" type="text" id="002"  size="50" />
                </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="right"><span class="TextAB"><strong>Email:</strong></span></div></td>
                <td><div align="left">
                  <input name="three" type="text" id="textfield3"  size="50" />
                </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="right"><span class="TextAB"><strong>Password:</strong></span></div></td>
                <td><div align="left">
                  <input name="four" type="text" id="textfield4"  size="50" />
                </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="right"><span class="TextAB"><strong>Phone:</strong></span></div></td>
                <td><div align="left">
                  <input name="five" type="text" id="textfield5"  size="30" />
                </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td valign="top"><div align="right"><span class="TextAB"><strong>Address 1:</strong></span></div></td>
                <td><div align="left">
                  <textarea name="six" cols="50" rows="3" wrap="virtual" id="textfield6"></textarea>
                  <br />
                  <span class="TextA style1">Please fill out full address, building number, street, city,state &amp; zip</span></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="right"><span class="TextAB"><strong>Address 2:</strong></span></div></td>
                <td><div align="left">
                  <input name="seven" type="text" id="textfield7"  size="50" />
                </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="right"><span class="TextAB"><strong>Pick-Up City:</strong></span></div></td>
                <td><div align="left">
                  <select name="eight" id="select">
                    <option value="Malabar">Malabar</option>
                    <option value="Ocala">Ocala</option>
                    <option value="Orlando">Orlando</option>
                    <option value="Orlando - Charles Schwab">Orlando - Charles Schwab</option>
                    <option value="West Palm Beach">West Palm Beach</option>
                  </select>
                </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="right"><span class="TextAB"><strong>State:</strong></span></div></td>
                <td><div align="left">
                  <select name="nine" id="select2">
                    <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                  </select>
                </div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="left"></div></td>
                <td><div align="left"></div></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div align="left"></div></td>
                <td><label>
                  <div align="left"><a href="#" class="TextE" onclick="javascript:Terms();document.getElementById('ch1').disabled=false;document.getElementById('ch2').disabled=false;"/><span class="TextE"><strong>Click to read MEMBER AGREEMENT<br />
                          <br />
                    </strong></span></a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="ch1" name="ch1" value="" disabled/>
                    <span class="TextE"><strong>I have read the Terms of Agreement</strong></span></div>
                </label></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td width="129" valign="bottom"><INPUT TYPE="image" name="ch2" id="ch2" value="" SRC="images/submitbutton.jpg" WIDTH="111"  HEIGHT="136" BORDER="0" ALT="SUBMIT" disabled></td>
          </tr>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table> </form></td></tr>
```

any help would be appreciated

why when i try to submit it wont go to my email?

i do have it set to when submitted it will go to another page where they pay for membership
but i am wanting the information from the form to go to myself so i can see who joins up on the website.

Comment: Suggest reading: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Answer (score 8):

```
      $message = "First Name:" $_POST['one'];
                 "Last Name:" $_POST['two'];
                 "Email:" $_POST['three'];
                 "Password:" $_POST['four'];
                 "Phone:" $_POST['five'];
                 "Address 1:" $_POST['six'];
                 "Address 2:" $_POST['seven'];
                 "Pick Up City:" $_POST['eight'];
                 "State:" $_POST['nine'];
```

should be:

```
      $message = "First Name:" . $_POST['one'] . "\n" .
                 "Last Name:" . $_POST['two'] . "\n" .
                 "Email:" . $_POST['three'] . "\n" .
                 "Password:" . $_POST['four'] . "\n" .
                 "Phone:" . $_POST['five'] . "\n" .
                 "Address 1:" . $_POST['six'] . "\n" .
                 "Address 2:" . $_POST['seven'] . "\n" .
                 "Pick Up City:" . $_POST['eight'] . "\n" .
                 "State:" . $_POST['nine'];
```

Weren't you getting parse errors from PHP? Your code is not even close to valid syntax. Strings are concatenated using `.`, not just putting them next to each other. And you had a `;` between each line, which ends the assignment. The remaining lines are not any kind of valid PHP statement.

You need to bone up on basic PHP coding.

Comment: ty bud, it posts now but only thing the information from the field wont show anything typed in, only thing i see is the titles but the post 'one' etc it shows blank

Comment: Is `send.php` also the script that contains the form?

Comment: Replace the redirect to the other page with `var_dump($_POST)`, what does it display?

Comment: well i have it to post it to the database as well seems like its not posting to the database and i got 1 email but then havent gotten anything again

Comment: I can't help you if you won't do the troubleshooting steps I suggest.

Comment: i have <form name="form1" method="post" action="joinsend.php" onSubmit="return joinsend();"> above my form so once i submit it goes there. it submits the data when it goes to the joinsend.php page, which one should i put the php code to send the form data?

Comment: You have two forms on the page? Only one of them can be submitted, the other is ignored.

Comment: Then I don't understand. Does it go to send.php or joinsend.php? And what does the `joinsend()` JS function do?

Comment: Sorry, I can't deal with someone who doesn't even know the basics right now. You need to hire a real programmer, not get randoms on the Internet to debug your code for you.

Comment: @Ryan if you are trying to call a PHP function on the "submit" action, you **can't** do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

use the below

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

      $to = "ry@cbpar.com"; 
      $subject = "New Membership Sign Up"; 
      $message = "First Name:".$_POST['one'];
      $message.=  "Last Name:". $_POST['two'];
      $message.=  "Email:". $_POST['three'];
      $message.=  "Password:". $_POST['four'];
      $message.=  "Phone:" .$_POST['five'];
      $message.=  "Address 1:" .$_POST['six'];
      $message.=  "Address 2:" .$_POST['seven'];
      $message.=  "Pick Up City:" .$_POST['eight'];
      $message.= "State:" .$_POST['nine'];
```

and also there is a problem in Your **mail** function. and You have not use **$header**. use **mail** function like below:-

```
      $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                 'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
                 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

         mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    ?>
```

Comment: The headers parameter is optional.

Comment: @Barmar yes you are right. but have You tried the above code?

Comment: I haven't tried any code. BTW, you're missing the `.` for string concatenation in all your `$message` assignments, just like the OP's original code.

Comment: @Barmar I request You to check twice my above code because everybody's coding style are not same.

Comment: well i tried the one Barmar mentioned and now i have no syntax errors only thing is the form hasnt been emailing

Comment: It has nothing to do with style, it's PHP syntax. You need a `.` between `"First Name"` and `$_POST['one']`.

Comment: the send.php seems fine thanks barmar, just curious on if u should put  <form method="post" action="send.php"> in the join.php code or the joinsend.php (which has the insert to database codes)?